# C++ Integer Types

Tags: c++, compilation

I'm currently reading through Crash Course C++ and have a question regarding types.

If I declare and initialize both an `int` and a `long long` variable on a 64-bit machine running Linux to the decimal value 4, does the compiler recognize the wasted bytes and make changes to the underlying type? This is probably a no, as at some point that field may take on a value that would cause overflow with a smaller type (i.e. going from 8 bytes to 4).

I've read a little about object byte reordering during compilation in c++; that compilers can sometimes rearrange fields to minimize padding in memory. Just wondering if there is a similar optimization that happens for numeric types.

Comment: I think you have misconceptions about CPU design. Most of the time, there is no notion of waste, since a 64-bit CPU always stores 64-bit numbers in their registers, no matter the value of the integers.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that the compiler will change the size of a variable. It might do so because of the *as if* rule, but if it can reliably do that, it means that the variable is used is a very simple context, for example assigned (or initialized) once from a constant and then only used in the same compilation unit and its address is not used (that last point if often said *odr-usage* for One Definition Rule).

But in that case, the compiler will simply optimize out the variable because it can directly use its value, so it will use no memory at all...